# Expanding string with trailing zeros in Perl

Tags: string, perl, format, printf

I have to handle part numbers, what are alphanumeric strings. Part numbers are 14 characters long, but part structure (s.c. upper level components) numbers are shorter. In metadata conversion upper level part numbers need to be expanded to the full length of 14 characters with tailing zeros.

I came up with the following solution

```
my $number = "M30SA0000002"; # same upper level part number
my $len = 14;

if (length($number) < $len) {
  print "Number [$number] is smaller, length (" . length ($number) . ")\n";
  $number = sprintf("%-${len}s", $number);
  $number =~ tr/ /0/;
}
print "\New number [$number], length (" . length ($number) . ")\n"
```

Here's output

```
Number [M30SA0000002] is smaller, length (12)
New number [M30SA000000200], length (14)
```

While this produces desirable result, this fills bit awkward to execute this simple task in 2 lines. Is there any way to do it in one line? Shame that `sprintf` doesn't provide a way to expand string with any trailing characters.

Production environment is run on Windows Server machines, Perl version `5.14.2.1`, no CPAN modules, only core modules available.

Edit:
I've benchmark 4 solutions

```
use Benchmark qw(:all);
timethese(10000000, {
            'While' => sub { my $number = "M30SA0000002"; $number .= '0' while 14 > length $number; },
            'Repeat' => sub { my $number = "M30SA0000002"; $number .= '0' x (14 - length $number); },
            'Substring' => sub { my $number = "M30SA0000002"; $number = substr($number . "0" x 14, 0, 14); },
            'Sprintf' => sub { my $number = "M30SA0000002"; $number = sprintf("%-14s", $number); $number =~ tr/ /0/; },
});
```

Here's result:

```
Benchmark: timing 10000000 iterations of Repeat, Sprintf, Substring, While...
    Repeat:  2 wallclock secs ( 1.65 usr +  0.00 sys =  1.65 CPU) @ 6045949.21/s (n=10000000)
   Sprintf:  3 wallclock secs ( 3.90 usr +  0.00 sys =  3.90 CPU) @ 2564102.56/s (n=10000000)
 Substring:  3 wallclock secs ( 2.78 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.78 CPU) @ 3602305.48/s (n=10000000)
     While:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.81 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.81 CPU) @ 3561253.56/s (n=10000000)
```

Repetition solution seems to be fastest of them all.

Comment: [String::Formatter](http://p3rl.org/String::Formatter), for when you want to extend `sprintf` and realise you can't.

Comment: String::Formatter is not a core Perl module. I can't use CPAN modules or at least I need to justify it's usage, but I have to go through very long approval process. So I'll skip this one for sure.

Comment: What makes random code off the Web (Stack Overflow) okay, but not (CPAN) thousand-fold tested that's productively in use elsewhere?

Comment: I don't have access to production environment and I cannot install there anything. Installations are done by other department. No much I can do.

Comment: I see, the deployment angle. You can almost always module copy code to have it deployed. That's more practical than reinventing the wheels badly and laboriously.

Comment: Your 'Substring' sub, at least as appears in your code snippet, is a typo'd duplicate of the 'Repeat' sub.

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed the code and benchmark results were changed too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `while` modifier together with an "append" assignment:

```
$number .= '0' while 14 > length $number;
```

or do some math and use the repetition operator (thanks @[loldop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/826614/loldop)):

```
$number .= '0' x (14 - length $number);
```

Comment: `$number.='0'x(14 - length $number)`?

Comment: Our program already have lots of loops. What can you say about provided solutions performance?

Answer (score 3):

One-step solution is to append a lot of `0`'s and chop off the ones you don't need:

```
$number = substr($number . "0" x 14, 0, 14);
```